# How can I copy a action in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I use cocos2dx 2.2.3. Now I need duplicate a ccsequence or ccspawn. But copy() don't work.

my code:

```
layerParticalsFront->runAction(action);
layerParticalsBack->runAction(action->copy());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example :

```
CCScaleBy* action1 = CCScaleBy::create(1.0f, 1.5f);

CCScaleBy* action2 = (CCScaleBy*)action1->copy()->autorelease();
```

Answer (score 0):

It changed a bit over time, this is how you can do it now.

```
ScaleBy* action1 = ScaleBy::create(1.0f, 1.5f);
ScaleBy* action2 = action1->clone();
```