# How can I 'reuse' cocos2d::action?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to make an animation sequence with cocos2d-x. I want to move sprites downwards by a certain distance one after another.

This is my first attempt:

```
auto fallAction = MoveBy::create(0.2f, Vec2(0, -director->getWinSize().height));
auto fallActionEase = EaseIn::create(fallAction, 2.0f);
auto fallStretch = ScaleBy::create(0.1f, 1.0f, 1.2f);
auto fall = Spawn::create(fallActionEase, fallStretch, NULL);
auto landTremble = EaseElasticOut::create(ScaleTo::create(0.5f, _finalScale));

this->getK()->runAction(Sequence::create(Delay::create(0.5f), fall, landTremble));
this->getA()->runAction(Sequence::create(Delay::create(1.0f), fall, landTremble));
this->getW()->runAction(Sequence::create(Delay::create(1.5f), fall, landTremble));
```

But it doesn't work, as discussed [here] ([Reuse cocos2d actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805112/reuse-cocos2d-actions)).

Then I found that [I can copy actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838226/how-can-i-copy-a-action-in-cocos2dx), but then I also found that Clonable::copy() is now deprecated (seems that it doesn't even exist in v3.6!)

I ended up nesting lambdas, like [here](https://github.com/Clpsplug/CCADXKawazLogo/blob/923b39c356a14931c25ec0af81b3c0902b373ab1/Classes/LogoScene.cpp) (line 246 to 254.)

I want to 'reuse' `actions` in a good manner! What I want to achieve is the following:

- Make the very same animation mentioned above
- Still `creating` **only one** `Action` to determine the movement of sprites
- Easy-to-maintain code

---

**EDIT:** To prevent link rot, I'll paste the code where I nested lambdas. Not very smart.

```
auto DesiredAction = Sequence::create(wait4Frog, Fall, Spawn::create(FallSound, LandTremble,CallFunc::create([this, Fall, LandTremble](){
    this->getA1()->runAction(Sequence::create(Fall, Spawn::create(LandTremble,CallFunc::create([this, Fall, LandTremble](){
        this->getW()->runAction(Sequence::create(Fall, Spawn::create(LandTremble,CallFunc::create([this, Fall, LandTremble](){
            this->getA2()->runAction(Sequence::create(Fall, Spawn::create(LandTremble,CallFunc::create([this, Fall, LandTremble](){
                this->getZ()->runAction(Sequence::create(Fall, LandTremble, NULL));
            }), NULL), NULL));
        }), NULL), NULL));
    }), NULL), NULL));
}), NULL), NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
Action* createSequence(float delay)
{
    auto fall = Spawn::create(
        EaseIn::create(MoveBy::create(0.2f, Vec2(0, -director->getWinSize().height)), 2.0f),
        ScaleBy::create(0.1f, 1.0f, 1.2f),
        NULL
    );
    auto landTremble = EaseElasticOut::create((ScaleTo::create(0.5f, _finalScale)));
    return Sequence::create(Delay::create(delay), fall, landTremble, NULL);
}
```

then you can use this function:

```
this->getK()->runAction(createSequence(0.5f));
this->getA()->runAction(createSequence(1.f));
this->getW()->runAction(createSequence(1.5f));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Why didn't I think of that! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As the accepted answer mentioned, you can encapsulate the definition of an action into a function, requiring the variations as parameters. Then reuse the function.

And there is another way if you just need exactly the same action for each time. You can create an action, retain it, then for each time use

```
someNode -> runAction( action->clone() );
```

as the action is retained, it needs to be released in the end.